# Flutter - DataTables - Can we have a single edit column for editing rows?

Tags: flutter, dart, datatables, rows, edit

I know we can edit individual cells in the DataTable by having a TextField in the DataCell:

```
    dataRows.add(
      DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(
          TextFormField(
            style: AppTextStyle.textStyleRegular,
            initialValue: _value,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            onFieldSubmitted: (val) {
              //print('onSubmited $val');
            },
          ),
          showEditIcon: true,
        ),
        ...
```

What I need is to have a single column with edit icon for each row. Clicking on the edit icon should make the cells in the row editable. Is it possible to do so? How will I know which cell was edited in such a case?

It should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Means you want a TextField at the top and list of items below that then if you click 2nd item Textfield gets editable and edited value should reflect on the same item?

Comment: No, I have a DataTable, I just need another column in it. And while the other columns (cells) show some value, the cells in this column will only have an edit icon.

Comment: are you passing any value to define which cell should have an edit icon? Or you also may share your UI.

Comment: Please check the image I have added.

Comment: Right now your all rows has edit icons, so now you want that only some of them will have an edit icon?

Comment: All will have the icon.

Comment: you can check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `sample code` below to get your expected result

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<bool> _isEditable = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          _isEditable.add(false);
          return Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: Text("#$index")),
              Expanded(child: TextFormField(
                enabled: _isEditable[index],
                controller: TextEditingController(text: "User $index"),
              )),
              Expanded(child: TextFormField(
                enabled: _isEditable[index],
                controller: TextEditingController(text: "${index*5} KG"),
              )),
              IconButton(onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  _isEditable[index] = !_isEditable[index];
                });
              }, icon: Icon(Icons.edit)),
            ],
          );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Before pressign edit

[image]
After clicking edit

[image]

Comment: The edit button doesn't work in this case

Comment: Have you used same code that I have shared?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: let me share you a link

Comment: It's working fine even on dart pad have you checked by clicking on the edit field after clicking edit button because it has no visual difference for now